# How can I make my shell behave like vim? 

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ubuntu-11.04

How can I make my shell behave like vim? I've seen other developers do it but I never got it installed/set up on my machine.

Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put this in your ~/.bashrc:

```
set -o vi
```

Then you can edit your command line using vi keys/commands instead of emacs keys/commands.

Comment: ................yes!

Comment: And for zsh: bindkey -v

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have to edit my .bashrc.  I just set this on the command line.

`$ set -o vi`

For more info with examples and a downloadable cheat sheet please see http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet/